# Listing base class instances without getting the inherited instances

Tags: spring-roo

I am new to Roo and here is my first exploration project base:

```
// Spring Roo 1.2.5.RELEASE [rev 8341dc2] log opened at 2014-07-28 18:39:08
project --topLevelPackage this.is.my.package --projectName my-project
entity jpa --class ~.domain.Equipment --testAutomatically --activeRecord --inheritanceType JOINED 
field string --fieldName name
field string --fieldName weight
field number --type int --fieldName cost
field enum --fieldName coinType --type ~.domain.CoinType
entity jpa --class ~.domain.Armor --extends ~.domain.Equipment --testAutomatically  --activeRecord
field enum --fieldName category --type ~.domain.ArmorCategory --notNull --column CATEGORY
field number --type int --fieldName bonus --class ~.domain.Armor --value 0 
perform tests
web mvc setup
web mvc all --package ~.web
exit
```

When I run the application, I create and save an armor instance. When listing the equipment list, I can see my newly created armor and I am even able to edit it as an equipment class. But, when I try to save, I get an error.

**Here is my question : how can I prevent the armor's instances to be listed into the "Equipment" section and to be displayed only into their own section: the "Armor" section? I mean, what is the best way to achieve it?**

Note: the equipment class may be used independently, this is why it is not an abstract class. Later on, I will create other sub classes of Equipment.

Thanks

### The first hand solution (post edit)

1. I created a new abstract class called `Gear` with all the equipment's properties.
2. I updated the Equipment class to remove all its properties. I also moved the `@RooJpaActiveRecord(inheritanceType = "JOINED")` annotation from the Equipment class to the Gear class. And I also changed its type to "TABLE_PER_CLASS".
3. Finally, I updated the Equipment and Weapon classes to use the Gear class as their base class.

I ran the following commands:

```
perform tests
web mvc setup
web mvc all --package ~.web
exit
```

Then I ran the application with the well known `mvn tomcat:run`

Now, after creating some weapons, I clic the `List all Equipments` link and it is empty; just as I expected. I can see theses weapons only when I click the `List all Armors` link.

I don't really think it is the best way to do it but it works. Anybody has a better solution?

Comment: I think will be useful to identify the problem if you include more information: Exception throw, Does Itegration test finish OK?,...

Comment: IMO, the exact error message or stack trace is not usefull here. The fact that there is an error when I try to save the weapon as an equipment is just normal because the `Equipment_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord` just don't know how to save the `Weapon` subclass (unless you tell me that the Roo framework should know how to do this). In fact, I implemented a solution that worked. I will put into my original request but I still want to know if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: I forgot to tell: all tests passed very well: within Roo as well as outside by invoking `mvn clean install test verify`. No error at all.

Comment: Your script (with some fixes like project package, adding jpa setup Hipersonic and remove missing enum) works for me. When I create an "Armor" I can show it in "Armor" and "Equipment" list. I'm using [gvNIX 1.3.1](http://gvnix.googlecode.com) (which works over Roo 1.2.4).

Comment: I guess I was not clear enough: I don't want armors to be listed into the "Equipment" list, only into the "Armor" list and my question was exactly about the best way to do it.

Comment: Do you want to remove the "Equipment" list or just filter its result?